# PostsControllers.php doesn't exist in my Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I'm watching a course on Laravel, and the teacher accesses a file called PostsController.php in app/Http/Controllers, but in my project, the class is missing.

I've installed the same release of Laravel that the teacher has, Laravel 5.2. Why don't I have the file? Is this file deprecated in future versions?

Comment: Do not add new questions. If you got another problem or question, ask new one.

Comment: The teacher created that file. You either missed a step, or it's a bad tutorial that's neglecting to explain steps.

Comment: Thanks Orlowski, english is not my native language so its hard for me to explain myself, now I have to re-write the question you deleted, next time I chose your incomplete answer as the correct so you can have your fake points and sleep well at night

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PostsController.php` is not there at the very beginning. Please open terminal/iTerm, go to the project folder and run the following artisan command:

```sh
php artisan make:controller PostsController
```

By the way, 5.2 is a very old version. What course are you learning? Laracasts?

Please use the latest version, which is 5.8.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I added an update to the question, what is your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have that file because it's not part of the framework - it's part of your application so you must create it yourself, either by from scratch, using any text editor/IDE of your choice, or with help of [artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan):

```
php artisan make:controller PostsController
```

Also I'd not really spend my time on v5.2 - this is ancient version (released December 21, 2015). Current version is 5.8.